# Not able to expose deployment using kubernetes in google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I used the below command to build my spring boot application for deployment in google cloud.

```
mvn clean install && docker build -t eu.gcr.io/XXX/demo .
gcloud builds submit --tag eu.gcr.io/XXX/demo
kubectl run demo-server --image eu.gcr.io/XXX/demo
kubectl expose deployment demo-server --type=LoadBalancer –port=8080
```

And I can access my application externally. I can delete and redeploy my application using:

```
kubectl delete deployment demo-server 
kubectl run demo-server --image eu.gcr.io/XXX/demo
```

It is all working fine, but when I tried to expose the same application on different port say 8081, it failed to complain `Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "demo-server" already exists`

 How can I change the service port?

Comment: How did you try to change the service?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by

```
kubectl get services
kubectl delete services demo-server
```

I was deleting deployment but service was still available